# Order of $(1~2~3~4) \in S_4$

Tags: group-theory

Given permutation group $S_4$. The problem here is I need to find the order of it.
The order of $a \in G$ is defined as the least natural number such that $a^n = e$ as e is the identity in $G$. This is a multiple choice questions, and the choice given is 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.
I understand about what $a^n = e$ means here, but somehow I can't figure out about it in permutation group.
Could anyone explain me a little to approach the problem?

Comment: Can you calculate $a^2$ for $a=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$? $a^3$? etc.

Comment: The order of $(i_1~i_2~\cdots~i_n)$ is $n$.

Comment: thank you. Now I got idea to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

$(1~2~3~4)$ means the permutation that takes $\{1,2,3,4\}$ on a cycle, i.e. $\begin{cases} 1 \mapsto 2 \\ 2 \mapsto 3 \\ 3 \mapsto 4 \\ 4 \mapsto 1 \end{cases}$

It is a $4$-cycle, so it takes exactly $4$ times to go back to the original, i.e. the order is $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1: just do it: calculate powers of $a$ until you get the identity permutation. If you’ve forgotten how to compose permutations, look it up in your notes.

Approach 2: think about how the permutation acts on a set (say, on the the letters in the string “abcd”. How many times do you have to repeat the action until the string is back in its original state?

Answer (score 0):

let c= (1 2 3 4).

c is a 4-cycle, its length is 4. you need to compose c 4 times to obtain the identity of $S_4$:

$c= (1 2 3 4)$

$c^2= (1 3)( 2 4)$

$c^3= (1 4 3 2)$

$c^4= I_d$

Therefore the order of c is 4.